# What counts as a "demon"?

Tags: angel-n-devil

On the show *Angel 'N' Devil*, we're told that Chi An's Demon Axe, logically enough, only works against demons. Unfortunately, what counts as a demon seems to be pretty unclear. There are a few examples, but they seem to cause more confusion than anything else.

Things that definitely count as a demon (axe activates):

- Hsiao Hsiung under the influence of the Daycrawler and Nightcrawler seeds he's collected.

Things that probably don't count as a demon (axe doesn't activate):

- Hsiao Hsiung under the control of a high-level Purebred Daycrawler.
- Evil Purebred Daycrawlers.

If anything qualified as a "demon" in the show, I would expect it to be Daycrawlers and Nightcrawlers.

So, what actually counts as a demon for the purposes of the Demon Axe?